# Manipulating Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, amazon-dynamodb

I am pretty new to javascript so bear with me!

So I have some data that I am pulling out of an AWS DynamoDB via a lambda script tied to an API gateway.

So I have a javascript function on my page that issues a GET request for the data and this works great. I am able to get the data. When I get it, it looks like this:

```
{"Items":[{"issue":"my issue","email":"my@email.com","caseDate":1496543576984,"phone":"1234567890","status":"queueing","enterpriseID":"john.smith"},{"issue":"Test issue 02","email":"john.smithy@company.com","caseDate":1496543945585,"phone":"1234567890","status":"queueing","enterpriseID":"john.smithy"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}
```

So I am trying to build a dynamic table on a web page with the data. This is the code that I have. Notice the map function where I am trying to change the order of the Items.issue, Items.caseDate etc to match up with the column headings.

```js
        var API_URL = 'https://myapi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/cases';
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: API_URL,

                success: function(data){
                    
                    //alert(data);
                    
                    table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");

                    var tableHeader = document.createElement("thead");
                    
                    var headerNames = ["Date", "Enterprise ID", "Client Phone", "Client Email",
                                      "Case Status", "Client Issue"];
                    
                    headerNames.forEach(function(header){
                        var tableHeaderItem = document.createElement("th");
                        var headerText = document.createTextNode(header.toString());
                        
                        tableHeaderItem.appendChild(headerText);
                        tableHeader.appendChild(tableHeaderItem);
                        
                    });

                    table.appendChild(tableHeader);

                    data.Items.forEach(function(queueItem){

                        var myTableRow = document.createElement("tr");
                        myTableRow.setAttribute("id", queueItem.date);
                        
                        var arr1 = $.map(queueItem, function(value, index) {
                            return [value];
                        });

                        const map =[2,5,3,1,4,0]
                        const arr3 = Array.apply(null, Array(map.length))
                        arr3.map((d, i) => arr3[map[i]] = arr1[i]);
                        
                        arr3.forEach(function(item){
                            var tableItem = document.createElement("td");
                            var itemText = document.createTextNode(item);
                            
                            tableItem.appendChild(itemText);
                            myTableRow.appendChild(tableItem);
                        });

                        table.appendChild(myTableRow);
                    })
                    document.getElementById("queueTable").appendChild(table);
                }
            }); 
        });
```

So the issue is that once I pull the actual data out of one of the items and shove it into an array to iterate over it, its in the wrong order. How can I fix this cause that map function sounds great but it doesn't work.

I should get me:

```
mapping["ID","phone","issue","caseDate","status","email"]
```

But it actually gets me:

```
mapping["caseDate","ID","phone","email","status","issue"]
```

Help! I have been beating my head against the wall for 3 hours now google searching etc and I just cant quite get what I need.

Comment: Object property iteration order actually [is specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) starting with ES2015, but I don't know if one can depend on it yet.  Nor do I think one ever should. (This in response to a now-deleted comment.)

Comment: So would there be a way to do this in lambda to get the data out of DynamoDB in a more predictable way? I just need to be able to generate a dynamic table based on whats in dynamoDB and stick it on a web page.

Comment: I know nothing about Dynamo, but you should be able to use the data supplied and format it how you like.  I have an answer below suggesting a more straightforward way than a list of headers and a list of reordering indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `headerNames` and those internal mappings, could you use a data structure like this instead?:

```
const fields = [
  {name: 'caseDate', header: 'Date'},
  {name: 'issue', header: 'Client Issue'}, 
  {name: 'email', header: 'Client Email'},
  {name: 'phone', header: 'Client Phone'},
  {name: 'status', header: 'Case Status'},
  {name: 'enterpriseID', header: 'Enterprise ID'}
]
```

You could loop over these in order for the headers, pulling off the `header` property, and for each row, pulling out the named field from the data via something like `item[field.name]`.

That looks cleaner overall.